# Empty data returning from many to many relationship laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I've two model called application and user.

### Application

id | name

### user

id | first name

### application_user

id | application_id | user_id | comment| rating | like

Here is the model classes

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\ModelValidator;

class Application extends ModelValidator
{
    //
    protected $table = "application";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','application_user','application_id','user_id')->withPivot(['rating','like','comment'])->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function getComment()
    {
        $comments = array();

        foreach ($this->user as $user) {
            $comments[] = $user->comment;
        }

        return compact($comments);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends ModelValidator implements AuthenticatableContract,CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable,CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'user';

    public function application()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Application')->withPivot(['rating','like','comment'])->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

But when i run the below code it prints empty array.

```
$apps = \App\Application::all();

        foreach ($apps as $app) {
            print_r($app->getComment());
        }
```

Why its returning empty array  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Moin, can you explain me that any relationship is exists between application and user table? because i can't find user_id in application table or application_id in user table. it's return empty array because laravel not find any relationship between user and application table right

Comment: the relationship between application and user is many to many,thats why there is another table called application_user.you ill find the ids from that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your relationship like

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\ModelValidator;

class Application extends ModelValidator
{
    //
    protected $table = "application";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicationUser','application_id','id')
               ->withPivot(['rating','like','comment'])->withTimestamps();
    }

}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends ModelValidator implements AuthenticatableContract,CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable,CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'user';

    public function application()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Application')->withPivot(['rating','like','comment'])->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

change your code like this.

```
foreach ($apps as $app) {
    print_r($app->user);
}
```

Now you get data from application_user table, you got empty result because of you trying to find a data into user table so for that you got empty result.

Comment: it does return some data but in my case i need the comments from the pivot table

Comment: it's working for me it's return data from application_user table